# Windows c socket : select() gives WSAENOTSOCK error

Tags: c, windows, sockets, visual-studio-2015, winsock

I am using winsock to connect to remote server. I was success in connecting the socket, but when i try to get socket details using select, it says socket does not exist(**WSAENOTSOCK**).

**N.B :** I am executing this code as Visual studio win console application and my OS is Windows 8.

***My code*** (Assume code execution starts from run_client function and test struct has all options). Also , functions are in different files, so i need to call WSAStartup multiple times

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_DEPRECATE_MEMORY
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int run_client(struct test * test)
{
    int startup;
    int result = 0;
    fd_set read_set, write_set, excep_fd;
    struct timeval now;
    struct timeval* timeout = NULL;
    struct iperf_stream *sp;

    FD_ZERO(&excep_fd);

    if (soc_connect(test) < 0)
        return -1;

    printf("Run client : success in making socket\n");

    memcpy(&read_set, &test->read_set, sizeof(fd_set));
    memcpy(&write_set, &test->write_set, sizeof(fd_set));

    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return -1;
    }

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
    }


    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    result = select(test->ctrl_sck + 1, &read_set, 0, 0, &tv);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
    {
        switch (WSAGetLastError())
        {
            case WSANOTINITIALISED:
                printf("select_result error  : WSANOTINITIALISED\n");
                break;
            case WSAEFAULT:
                printf("select_result error  : WSAEFAULT\n");
                break;
            case WSAENETDOWN:
                printf("select_result error  : WSAENETDOWN\n");
                break;
            case WSAEINTR:
                printf("select_result error  : WSAEINTR\n");
                break;
            case WSAEINPROGRESS:
                printf("select_result error  : WSAEINPROGRESS\n");
                break;
            case WSAENOTSOCK:
                printf("select_result error  : WSAENOTSOCK\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("select_result errors  : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
        }
        i_errno = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(test->ctrl_sck);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("select_result : timeout : %d\n", result);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }
}

int soc_connect(struct test *test)
{
    FD_ZERO(&test->read_set);
    FD_ZERO(&test->write_set);

    printf("Making cookie\n");

    make_cookie(test->cookie);

    printf("Success in Making cookie\n");

    /* Create and connect the control channel */
    if (test->ctrl_sck < 0)
    {
       test->ctrl_sck = netdial(test->settings->domain, Ptcp, test->bind_address, 0, test->server_hostname, test->server_port);
    }

    if (test->ctrl_sck < 0) {
        i_errno = IECONNECT;
        return -1;
    }

    FD_SET(test->ctrl_sck, &test->read_set);
    return 0;
}

void make_cookie(char *cookie)
{
    static int randomized = 0;
    char hostname[500];
    struct timeval tv;
    char temp[1000];

    if ( ! randomized )
        srand((int) time(0) ^ getpid());

    (void) gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
    (void) gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    (void) snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%s.%ld.%06ld.%08lx%08lx.%s", hostname, (unsigned long int) tv.tv_sec, (unsigned long int) tv.tv_usec, (unsigned long int) rand(), (unsigned long int) rand(), "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");

    memcpy(cookie, temp, 36);
    cookie[36] = '\0';
}

int netdial(int domain, int proto, char *local, int local_port, char *server, int port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *local_res = NULL, *server_res = NULL;
    int s;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    INT iRetval;

    char port_str[6];
    snprintf(port_str, 6, "%d", port);

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return -1;
    }

    if (local) {
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = domain;
        hints.ai_socktype = proto;
        if (getaddrinfo(local, port_str, &hints, &local_res) != 0)
        {
            WSACleanup();
            printf("Net dial : 0\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = domain;
    hints.ai_socktype = proto;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    if (getaddrinfo(server, port_str, &hints, &server_res) != 0)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }


    s = socket(server_res->ai_family, server_res->ai_socktype, server_res->ai_protocol);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (local)
        {
            if (local_res != NULL)
                freeaddrinfo(local_res);
        }
        freeaddrinfo(server_res);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Socket created\n");

    if (local) {
        if (local_port) {
            printf("Net dial : 3\n");
            struct sockaddr_in *lcladdr;
            lcladdr = (struct sockaddr_in *)local_res->ai_addr;
            lcladdr->sin_port = htons(local_port);
            local_res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)lcladdr;
        }

        if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) local_res->ai_addr, local_res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
            _close(s);
            WSACleanup();
            freeaddrinfo(local_res);
            freeaddrinfo(server_res);
            printf("Net dial : 4\n");
                return -1;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(local_res);
    }

    iResult = connect(s, server_res->ai_addr, (int)server_res->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(s);
        s = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(server_res);

    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Socket connected\n");

    WSACleanup();
    return s;
}
```

***Output***

```
Making cookie
Success in Making cookie
Socket created
Socket connected
Run client : success in making socket
The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay
select_result errors  : WSAENOTSOCK
```

I have googled this issue and tried many solutions but i cannot find a solution for mine. Can an one please help out please.

Comment: Are you sure Windows's version of the fd_set structure is compatible with memcpy()? Maybe you should actually keep a list of sockets in your `test` structure and fill the fd_set from the list each time...

Comment: Why are you calling `WSAStartup()` multiple times? And `WSACleanup()`? These should only be called once per process.

Comment: @EJP functions are in different c files. SO i need. Sorry for not mentioning in question.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. It doesn't even make sense. Winsock doesn't know how many .c files you have. You don't need to do this once per .c file. You need to do it once per process. I cannot imagine where you got this idea. Remove and retest.

Comment: @Medinoc: that is exactly what the code should be doing.  Keep a list of active sockets, and then populate a new `fd_set` each time `select()` needs to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> functions are in different files, so i need to call WSAStartup multiple times

No you don't. This is a fabrication on your part. You need to call `WSAStartup()` once, at the beginning of the process, and `WSACleanup()` once at the end of the process.

I cannot imagine how or where you got this idea, but it is wrong. Winsock neither knows nor cares how many .c files you have.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know about that. Thanks for the point. I tried WSAStartup() just once, at the beginning of the process. Now select() result changed from WSAENOTSOCK to zero. I tried t increase timeout to 10 sec, then also i get zero after 10 second.  Have any idea about this?

Comment: When `select()` returns 0, it means the timeout period elapsed. So whatever condition you are waiting on is clearly not being satisfied.